# How do I insert a variable in my json payload?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, payload

I am using the firebase realtime database to get data into my app. I am using json to sort my data and I try to get a variable as my value as shown in the code. I tried to use `JSON.stringify(favoriteMenu)` and `"{favoriteMenu}"` but that does not work. Does somebody has an idea? Thank you.

```
var favoriteMenu = "Pizza";
{
   "Menu" : {
     "09:09:2020" : {
       "Menu1" : favoriteMenu
     }
   }
}
```

I am new in json but the following is what I sued to get the results from the added image. But when I tried it with a variable it gives me an error when I want to import the json file to the realtime database from firebase.

```
{
  "Menu" : {
    "09:09:2020" : {
      "Menu1" : "Coconut Fish Curry"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The bottom `{}` object in your snippet is unused.  It is unclear what your issue is.

Comment: You are not assigning your object to a variable? Show the complete code ...

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it clarified it a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to set the key `Menu1` of the object at key `09:09:2020` which is inside object at key `Menu` to the value of the variable named `favoriteMenu` then:

```
var favoriteMenu = "Pizza";

var o = {
   "Menu" : {
     "09:09:2020" : {
       "Menu1" : favoriteMenu
     }
   }
};

o.Menu["09:09:2020"].Menu1 = favoriteMenu;

console.log(o.Menu["09:09:2020"].Menu1 === favoriteMenu);
```

Most likely you were confused about how to index object with keys like `09:09:2020`, as you can see it is possible by using square brackets and wrapping key as a string.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Unfortunately it does not work in my case. I don't know why. Thank you anyways!